# re enabling a text field

Tags: jquery, html

I have two  interrelated text fields(a and b) which both have a default value of 0 if value is entered into a, b is disabled. if value is entered into b, a is disabled. after entering the value into a, if I erase the value b becomes automatically enabled but I discovered that if I enter the default value 0 the disabled field will not be enabled and I want it to, any suggestions how I can go about reenabling b if I re enter 0 in a . thanks 
this is my code in my view

```
<div class="row form-group">
    <label for="DateTo" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Flat Discount Percent</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.vwdecimal0, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 7, id = "id_dispercent" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row form-group">
    <label for="DateTo" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Flat Discount Amount</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.vwdecimal1, new { @class = "form-control", @maxlength = 11, id = "id_disamount" })
    </div>
</div>
```

my script

```
var id_dispercent = document.getElementById('id_dispercent'),
    id_disamount = document.getElementById('id_disamount');

function enableToggle(current, other) {
    other.disabled = current.value.replace(/\s+/, '').length > 0;
}

id_dispercent.onkeyup = function () {
    enableToggle(this, id_disamount);
}

id_disamount.onkeyup = function () {
    enableToggle(this, id_dispercent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I finally solved this.

```
$("#id_disamount").change(function () {
            var com = $("#id_disamount").val();
            if (com > 0)
                $("#id_dispercent").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            else
                $("#id_dispercent").removeAttr("disabled");
        });

        $("#id_dispercent").change(function () {
            var com = $("#id_dispercent").val();
            if (com > 0)
                $("#id_disamount").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            else
                $("#id_disamount").removeAttr("disabled");
        });
```

it worked for disabling and reenabling the textbook when the other is back at the default.